# how to correlate the script of gmail login transaction?

Tags: loadrunner

I've application which uses the gmail login. When I enter the url of my application then the response will redirected to the gmail login page. After I login successfully the page will be redirected to my application. Problem is when I see the script I'm unable to know what data needs to be correlated. I've parameterized Email ID and password. And I Replayed it at the time login transaction the page is not redirected to My application. Please help me out.

Comment: when I replay the script, At the time of login transaction the page is not redirected to my application where I need to navigate

Answer (score 0):

Uhhmmmm, read your license agreement regarding pointing a performance testing tool at a site you do not own, manage, control or have written permission from those that do have that ownership.  Also, read your google license agreement for the use of automated tools against their services outside of the published and supported web services APIs.

License-wise, from both ends of this load, you are on unsupported foundations